# HTML input type="file" onchange="form.submit()" doesn't work with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to make the form for users to update their profile pictures auto-submit, whenever they put in a file. Here is my HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif" id="file" name="profile-picture" onchange="form.submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

My Python code:

```
@users.route("/account", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@users.route("/account/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if request.files:
            profile_picture = request.files["profile-picture"]
            picture_file = save_picture(profile_picture) # save_picture is a function I wrote
            current_user.image_file = picture_file
    
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your profile has been updated!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("users.account"))
```

Normally, onchange="form.submit()" would work perfectly fine, but it doesn't seem to work when I'm using Python Flask. The form would submit if I put a submit button, but does not submit automatically. Does anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Comment: are there any error messages in the browser console, or the website log?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write `profile_picture = request.form["profile-picture"]`.

Comment: In this case, request.files is the correct thing to do - request.form raises an error.